# SQLSTATE[42S22]: Error using when clause in Laravel 7 advance filter with raw sql

Tags: php, mysql, sql, backend, laravel-7

**UPDATED**
I am making a search filter and using raw sql in query builder, so there are min and max mileage and prices for the filters of cars in database, with assumed columns...
Actually I am calculating the prices and mileage in standard units which is Euro and kilometers in raw sql for application of operators on the output...
for example if user store 110 usd then it will be converted to 100 euro at first in raw sql then we will determine the results greater or lesser thans...
The method works for one condition but when I activate others it gives error that the assumed column is not found...

```
//query for min price:
    $product1 = DB::table('sellers') 
->leftJoin('users','sellers.user_id','=','users.id')
->leftJoin('prices_privates','sellers.id','=','prices_privates.user_id')
->when($request->get('price_min'), function($query) use ($request) {
                        $price = $request->get('price_min');
                        $usd = $this->currency(1 , 'USD');
                        $gbp = $this->currency(1 , 'GBP');
                        $cad = $this->currency(1 , 'CAD');
                        $aud = $this->currency(1 , 'AUD');
                        $mxn = $this->currency(1 , 'MXN');
                        $brl = $this->currency(1 , 'BRL');
                        $query->select("*",
                        \DB::raw('(CASE 
                       WHEN currency = "USD" THEN FORMAT((price * '.$usd.'),2)
                       WHEN currency = "GBP" THEN FORMAT((price * '.$gbp.'),2)
                       WHEN currency = "CAD" THEN FORMAT((price * '.$cad.'),2)
                       WHEN currency = "AUD" THEN FORMAT((price * '.$aud.'),2)
                       WHEN currency = "MXN" THEN FORMAT((price * '.$mxn.'),2)
                       WHEN currency = "BRL" THEN FORMAT((price * '.$brl.'),2)
                       WHEN currency = "EUR" THEN FORMAT((price * 1),2)
                       END) AS price_conv'))
                  ->having("price_conv" ,'>=', $price);
                })   
    //query for min mileage
 ->when($request->get('mileage_from'), function($query) use ($request) {
                        $mileage_from = $request->mileage_from;
                        $query->select("*",
                        \DB::raw('(CASE 
                            WHEN mileage_in = "miles" THEN mileage * 1.60934 
                            WHEN mileage_in = "km" THEN mileage + 0 
                            END) AS kilometers'))
                       ->having("kilometers" ,'>=', $mileage_from);
                    })

 //Radius Search
                
                ->when($request->input('distance_km')&& $request->input('loc_latitude') && $request->input('loc_longitude') , function ($query) use ($request){

                    $lat = $request->get('loc_latitude');
                    $long = $request->get('loc_longitude');
                    $radius = $request->get('distance_km');
                    $query->select("*",
                         \DB::raw('( 6371 * acos( cos( radians(?) ) *
                          cos( radians( location_privates.latitude ) )
                          * cos( radians( location_privates.longitude ) - radians(?)
                          ) + sin( radians(?) ) *
                          sin( radians( location_privates.latitude ) ) )
                         ) AS distance', [$lat, $long, $lat]))
                        ->having("distance", '<=', $radius);
                        // ->orderBy("distance",'asc');

                })

    ->get(['sellers.*',
                    'users.user_type',
                    'prices_privates.price',
                    'prices_privates.currency',
                    'location_privates.address',
                    'location_privates.latitude',
                    'location_privates.longitude'
                 ]);
```

[image]

if I comment one function the other works..
they do not work at the same time..
this problem is only with queries which includes raw sql.

Here the whole function :

```
    $product1 = DB::table('sellers') 
                        ->leftJoin('users','sellers.user_id','=','users.id')
                        ->leftJoin('location_privates','sellers.id','=','location_privates.user_id')
                        ->leftJoin('prices_privates','sellers.id','=','prices_privates.user_id')
                 
                                        
                    ->when($request->get('condition') == 'classic', function($query) use ($request) {
                        $year = Carbon::now()->format('Y');
                        $used = ($year - '20' );
                        $query->where('manufact_year', '<=', $used);
                    })  
                    ->when($request->get('condition') == 'used', function($query) use ($request) {
                        $year = Carbon::now()->format('Y');
                        $used = ($year - '20' );
                        $query->where('manufact_year', '>=', $used);
                    }) 
                    ->when($request->get('condition') == 'user', function($query) use ($request) {
                        $query->where('user_type', '=', 'user');
                    })
                    ->when($request->get('condition') == 'company', function($query) use ($request) {
                        $query->where('user_type', '=', 'company');
                    })

                    ->when($request->get('search_make'), function($query) use ($request) {
                        $make = $request->get('search_make');
                        $query->where('make', 'like', "%$make%");
                    })
                    
                    ->when($request->get('style'), function($query) use ($request) {
                        $style = $request->get('style');
                        $query->where('car_body', 'like', "%$style%");
                    })
                    ->when($request->get('model'), function($query) use ($request) {
                        $model = $request->get('model');
                        $query->where('model', 'like', "%$model%");
                    })
    
                    
                    ->when($request->get('color'), function($query) use ($request) {
                        $color = $request->get('color'); 
                        $query->where('color', 'like', "%$color%");
                    })
                    ->when($request->get('country'), function($query) use ($request) {
                        $country = $request->get('country');
                        $query->where('address', 'like', "%$country%");
                    })
                    
                    ->when($request->get('year_min'), function($query) use ($request) {
                        $query->where('manufact_year', '>=', $request->get('year_min'));
                    })
                    
                    
                    ->when($request->get('year_max'), function($query) use ($request) {
                        $query->where('manufact_year', '<=', $request->get('year_max'));
                    })
    
                  
                ->when($request->get('price_min') && $request->get('price_max'), function($query) use ($request) {
                    $price = $request->get('price_min');
                    $price_2 = $request->get('price_max');
                    $usd = $this->currency(1 , 'USD');
                    $gbp = $this->currency(1 , 'GBP');
                    $cad = $this->currency(1 , 'CAD');
                    $aud = $this->currency(1 , 'AUD');
                    $mxn = $this->currency(1 , 'MXN');
                    $brl = $this->currency(1 , 'BRL');

                    $query->select("*",

                    \DB::raw('(CASE 
                            

                        WHEN currency = "USD" THEN FORMAT((price * '.$usd.'),2)
                        WHEN currency = "GBP" THEN FORMAT((price * '.$gbp.'),2)
                        WHEN currency = "CAD" THEN FORMAT((price * '.$cad.'),2)
                        WHEN currency = "AUD" THEN FORMAT((price * '.$aud.'),2)
                        WHEN currency = "MXN" THEN FORMAT((price * '.$mxn.'),2)
                        WHEN currency = "BRL" THEN FORMAT((price * '.$brl.'),2)
                        WHEN currency = "EUR" THEN FORMAT((price * 1),2)
                        END) AS price_conv')
                        )
                        ->having('price_conv between $price and $price_2');
                        // ->having("price_conv" ,'<=', $price_2);
                     

                })
                
                // ->when($request->get('price_max'), function($query) use ($request) {
                //     $price_2 = $request->get('price_max');
                //     $usd = $this->currency(1 , 'USD');
                //     $gbp = $this->currency(1 , 'GBP');
                //     $cad = $this->currency(1 , 'CAD');
                //     $aud = $this->currency(1 , 'AUD');
                //     $mxn = $this->currency(1 , 'MXN');
                //     $brl = $this->currency(1 , 'BRL');

                //     $query->select("*",

                //     \DB::raw('(CASE 
                            

                //         WHEN currency = "USD" THEN FORMAT((price * '.$usd.'),2)
                //         WHEN currency = "GBP" THEN FORMAT((price * '.$gbp.'),2)
                //         WHEN currency = "CAD" THEN FORMAT((price * '.$cad.'),2)
                //         WHEN currency = "AUD" THEN FORMAT((price * '.$aud.'),2)
                //         WHEN currency = "MXN" THEN FORMAT((price * '.$mxn.'),2)
                //         WHEN currency = "BRL" THEN FORMAT((price * '.$brl.'),2)
                //         WHEN currency = "EUR" THEN FORMAT((price * 1),2)
                //         END) AS price_conv')
                //         )
                //         ->having('price_conv' ,'<=', $price_2);
                     

                // })

                        // WHEN currency = "miles" THEN 0

                // ->when($request->get('mileage_from'), function($query) use ($request) {
                //     $mileage_from = $request->mileage_from;

                //     $query->select("*",

                //     \DB::raw('(CASE 

                //         WHEN mileage_in = "miles" THEN mileage * 1.60934 

                //         WHEN mileage_in = "km" THEN mileage + 0 

                //         END) AS kilometers'))
                        
                //         ->having("kilometers" ,'>=', $mileage_from);
                // })
                
                // ->when($request->get('mileage_to') && $request->get('mileage_to') != '200000', function($query) use ($request) {
                //     $mileage_to = $request->get('mileage_to');
                //                     $query->select("*",

                //     \DB::raw('(CASE 

                //         WHEN mileage_in = "miles" THEN mileage * 1.60934 

                //         WHEN mileage_in = "km" THEN mileage + 0 

                //         END) AS kilometers'))

                //     ->having("kilometers", '<=', $mileage_to);
                // })
   
   //Radius Search
                
                // ->when($request->input('distance_km')&& $request->input('loc_latitude') && $request->input('loc_longitude') , function ($query) use ($request){

                //     $lat = $request->get('loc_latitude');
                //     $long = $request->get('loc_longitude');
                //     $radius = $request->get('distance_km');
                //     $query->select("*",
                //          \DB::raw('( 6371 * acos( cos( radians(?) ) *
                //           cos( radians( location_privates.latitude ) )
                //           * cos( radians( location_privates.longitude ) - radians(?)
                //           ) + sin( radians(?) ) *
                //           sin( radians( location_privates.latitude ) ) )
                //          ) AS distance', [$lat, $long, $lat]))
                //         ->having("distance", '<=', $radius);
                //         // ->orderBy("distance",'asc');

                // })

//End Radius Search

               
                ->get(['sellers.*',
                'users.user_type',
                'prices_privates.price',
                'prices_privates.currency',
                'location_privates.address',
                'location_privates.latitude',
                'location_privates.longitude'
                ]);
```

That part:

```
 '*, ( 6371 * acos( cos( radians(?) ) * ' at line 11 (SQL: select *, (CASE WHEN currency = "USD" THEN FORMAT((price * 0.8149295086),2) WHEN currency = "GBP" THEN FORMAT((price * 1.112309934),2) WHEN currency = "CAD" THEN FORMAT((price * 0.6396724877),2) WHEN currency = "AUD" THEN FORMAT((price * 0.629089079),2) WHEN currency = "MXN" THEN FORMAT((price * 0.0409567497),2) WHEN currency = "BRL" THEN FORMAT((price * 0.1568996627),2) WHEN currency = "EUR" THEN FORMAT((price * 1),2) END) AS price_conv, *, ( 6371 * acos( cos( radians(13.7563309) ) * cos( radians( location_privates.latitude ) ) * cos( radians( location_privates.longitude ) - radians(100.5017651) ) + sin( radians(13.7563309) ) * sin( radians( location_privates.latitude ) ) ) ) AS distance from `sellers` left join `users` on `sellers`.`user_id` = `users`.`id` left join `location_privates` on `sellers`.`id` = `location_privates`.`user_id` left join `prices_privates` on `sellers`.`id` = `prices_privates`.`user_id` having `price_conv` >= 100 and `distance` >= 500)
```

Comment: Some code seems to be missing. The problem is very clear, is on: `... acos( cos( radians(?) ) * ...` where you are passing a `?` to your query. Could you share the code that insert this part to your SQL? Usually this is some variable binding missing.

Comment: Yes that another filter which i have not pasted due to the length of code .... but the problem i same let me paste the code let me edit

Comment: It seems the ` \DB::raw` variables `[$lat, $long, $lat]` are not bidding even though you are checking for not empty values and the call seems ok. If possible, could you paste the full SQL that it is trying to execute.

Comment: okay let me paste everything

Comment: updated pasted the whole function in the last part

Comment: i was experimenting something in the max price query so there was some change but the problem is same

Comment: Oh, I've just asked for the SQL outputted in the error message, you can remove the rest of the code if you want.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/226821/discussion-between-bpanatta-and-ali).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your SQL have two `*` selectors, so you should remove the redundant "asterisks" and have only one.

First add a single "all" selector to the start of the query:

```php
$product1 = DB::table('sellers')
    ->select("*")
//...
```

After that, replace all the `select("*",` that comes before the `\DB::raw` statements with `addSelect(`. Like the following:

```php
// Old code
$query->select("*",
        \DB::raw('( 6371 * acos( cos( radians(?) ) *
```

```php
// New code
$query->addSelect(\DB::raw('( 6371 * acos( cos( radians(?) ) *
```

This will create a SQL with only a single "all" selector and add to it each of the custom selectors.